# Styling a Spinner, appcompat, material

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design

So my app theme extends from AppCompat's Material Light theme with Dark Action Bar.

I applied an accent color.

Now I am trying to use a Spinner on a dark backround and because of the theme, the spinner has a dark gray arrow which changes to accent color when pressed.

How can I make this spinner's arrow white so that it is prominent on a dark background?

Here's the image of the Spinner:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? If the dark area is created in Java you can look into `ContextThemeWrapper`.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I attached an image of the spinner.

Comment: I'd like the right arrow you see to be white in color while maintaining the accent color I applied.

Comment: The arrow is part of spinner's background so I'd go with a layer drawable with ripple on API 21+ and pre-colored chevron, because I can't tint in XML before Lollipop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the support library 22.1 enables use of android:theme attribute on views. That should help here.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to apply same spinner style app wide, then in your `values/styles.xml`, override [`spinnerStyle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#spinnerStyle) with your custom style, which derives from an appcompat type and override `android:background`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/AppSpinner</item>
</style>

<style name="AppSpinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/your_spinner_background</item>
</style>
```

If you need a quick way to generate a spinner background, try [android-holo-colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/), choose Colored Spinner and supply your accent color.

Comment: your answer helps if I am working with pre lollipop and I simply have to use a selector drawable and replace it in my theme as you explained, but with the new appcompat and lollipop widget accenting there should be a different way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

with android:background you can specify your own background resource. I find the arrow rather useless (tapping the spinner brings dropdown menu even without arrow) so if you don't want to draw a custom arrow image, just leave the background black or transparent.