# Do we need to specific its UI components (Spinner, EditText) colors explicitly when using AppCompat

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

Previously, I have a `DialogFragment`, which I doesn't specific its UI components (Spinner, EditText) colors explicitly.

### dialog_fragment_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"       
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/country_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" /> 

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapWords"
        android:maxLength="50"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using

- SherlockActionBar
- Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar
- android:minSdkVersion="10", android:targetSdkVersion="21"

It looks as following

[image]

After migrating to

- AppCompat
- Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
- android:minSdkVersion="10", android:targetSdkVersion="22"

It looks like the following

[image]

I was wondering, am I doing something wrong during my migration process? Is there really a need, to specific color for `DialogFragment` UI components (Spinner, EditText) colors explicitly?

Is there a way, to make the `DialogFragment` looks good, without having the manually assigning colors to Spinner, EditText, ... just like what we do (We let system to decide the best color for Spinner, EditText, ...) when we use SherlockActionBar?

Note, I don't specific theme in `Activity` or `DialogFragment`. I only specific theme in `Application`, and I expect my `Activity` or `DialogFragment` will inherit from `Application`'s.

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/..." >
```

The code for the `DialogFragment` is

### Source code for DialogFragment

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {

    public static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {
        return new MyDialogFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_layout, null);

        final Spinner countrySpinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.country_spinner);
        final EditText nameEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.name_edit_text);
        final CountryArrayAdapter countryArrayAdapter = new CountryArrayAdapter(this.getActivity());
        countrySpinner.setAdapter(countryArrayAdapter);
        nameEditText.setHint(R.string.new_watchlist_hint);
        nameEditText.setText(org.yccheok.jstock.watchlist.Utils.getDefaultWatchlistName());
        Utils.placeCursorAtEndOfText(nameEditText);

        final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity())
        .setTitle(R.string.new_watchlist_title)
        .setView(view)
        // Add action buttons
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        })           
        .create();

        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked
        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

                Button b = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        ...
                    }
                });
            }
        });            

        return dialog;
    }
```

### Code to show DialogFragment

```
private void showMyDialogFragment() {        
    FragmentManager fm = this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
    myDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
    myDialogFragment.show(fm, MY_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);        
}
```

Comment: Did you use the support.v7 version of AlertDialog?

Comment: So where's your code that actually creates the dialog?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I update the question. It is a pretty standard way to create and show dialog fragment.

Comment: No, I was talking about the code in `onCreateDialog()` to actually create the dialog - you've only included the code to build the view, not the dialog itself.

Comment: @ianhanniballake OK. I get your point. Edited. Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: I think I get what you mean, I should use AppCompatDialog ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Support Library version of AlertDialog, [support.v7.app.AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog.html), added in [Android Support Library 22.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html), brings a single material style dialog (and theming to the views within) to all API7+ devices. If you are using AppCompat, you should also be using the support library `AlertDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

The theme `Theme.Sherlock.Light` is technically a compatibility version of Holo.Light of Holo family. In appcompat library, the theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light` is the compatibility version of Material family. So the behavior above is to be expected because widgets like Spinner and EditText are [styled](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html) with new material design.

If you want to preserve Holo looks then you will have to specify your own styles starting from `values-v21` which you later inherit in v14 and v11. This post shows how to do it for spinner: [Styling a Spinner, appcompat, material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079903/styling-a-spinner-appcompat-material)